How to copy drivers on Shape Keys from one object to another?
I have two figures, one low poly and the other HD with the same height shape keys.
But one has drivers, the other does not.
I want to copy drivers from one model to another.
I tried using link object data and link animation data but nothing helped.
Any ideas on how to do this?
I found this example, but my figure has the same armature
Copying each driver separately takes too long

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

In the addon you found, Mesh Data Transfer, in the Source Armature and Target Armature fields, set the same armature: it works.


I checked it works, but you don’t have to connect the target armature.
